# Can someone translate this awk command?

Tags: linux, awk, command

```bash
awk '/^(E|I|D)@.*/ {p=0}; /^(E|I|D)@.*User Name: my_username.*_ACCESS_CHECK_.*/ {p=1; printf FILENAME ":" FNR ":"}; p { print }' ~/app_name/log/service/INFO.*
```

Can someone translate this awk command in easy language?

---

EDIT: here is the above formatted legibly by `gawk -o-`:

```
/^(E|I|D)@.*/ {
        p = 0
}

/^(E|I|D)@.*User Name: my_username.*_ACCESS_CHECK_.*/ {
        p = 1
        printf FILENAME ":" FNR ":"
}

p {
        print
}
```

Comment: "One-liners" are a problem for legibility. Step 1 in trying to understand any program is format it legibly so I've done that for you now by running it through `gawk -o-` and added it's output to your question. Read that, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you don't understand any of it, then let us know if you still have questions.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a line begins with `E`, `I` or `D`, immediately followed by `@` and followed by text which contains `User Name: my_username` and `_ACCESS_CHECK_`, in that order, a flag called `p` ("print") is set true.

While that flag is true, every line of input that passes through Awk is printed. While the flag is false, printing of lines is suppressed.

The `p` flag reverts to false when a line is read which begins with `E`, `I` or `O`, followed by `@`, that doesn't contain the two additional text matches. That line itself isn't printed.

Answer (score 0):

@`Yudha` :

it's bad form writing it as `printf FILENAME …`, without the formatting statement and without brackets

— treat `printf()` like `sprintf()`, a function, rather than like `print`, a statement

> `printf("%s", FILENAME ":" FNR ":")`

- or, preferably,

> ---
>
> `printf("%s:%u:", FILENAME, FNR)`
>
> ---

here's an example of how the original approach would fall apart - a file with the percentage sign in its filename:

```
 -rw-r--r--    1 501 staff  1036334374 Jul 21  2021 file%dxyz.txt


 :gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file%dxyz.txt FNR=1039321) 
 
     fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string

    `file%dxyz.txt:1039321:'
         ^ ran out for this one
```